# Is Visual Studio Subscription (earlier MSDN suscription) per user?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, msdn

I have just going through https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/pricing/ and found the prices to be 45 $/ month or 1199 $/year for Professional subscription. Is this cost per user? if so, do I need to purchase 100 subscriptions (4500 $ / per month!) for 100 developers in my company?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's per user. It's better described on the following page:
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/pricing-details/

Comment: @Swaym additionally you look if you qualify for the Microsoft Partner Program. As example the `Application Development` competence comes with 5 to 25 licenses for internal use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just looking for the same and you can be glad to have a price tag of $1199 - to me as single user located in Germany this turns into 1540€ on check-out, that would be $1813. VAT is only a small share of that difference.
Btw, the fee is for the first year, renewal will be relatively cheaper.

With your larger number of seats, you should also investigate the SKU 77D-00092 and 77D-00095 respectively. As I see them advertised in various places these still come with two years of MSDN subscription rather than the one year offered on the MS web site, also at a lower price. Maybe they are missing bundled Azure credits? Those SKUs appear to require an "Open License" plan with at least 5 seats - that's as far as I got.